# Python: global & change var reference

Tags: python, unit-testing, global-variables, global

Okay, I've been doing some tests, so I need to check the result every time I run a method. Because the test doesn't work properly.

I've made an example that works fine(not a test, but same behavior). In my test the result doesn't change, while in the example it changes.

**EXAMPLE**

```
def thread():

    global result
    import time
    time.sleep(0.5)
    result = 5/2
    Gtk.main_quit()


import threading
from gi.repository import Gtk
result = None
t = threading.Thread(target=thread, args=())
t.start()
Gtk.main()
print result

OUTPUT: 2
```

**TEST**

```
def testSi_Button_clicked(self):

        def thread(button=self.builder.get_object('Si_Button')):

            import time
            global result
            time.sleep(0.5)
            result = self.esci.Si_Button_clicked(button)
            print 'result ' + str(result)
            #Gtk.main_quit()


        import threading

        self.current_window = 'Home_Window' #DO NOT TRY WITH 'Azioni_Window'
        result = None
        t = threading.Thread(target=thread, args=())
        t.start()
        Gtk.main()
        print 'assert'
        print 'result ' + str(result)
        self.assertIsNotNone(result)

OUTPUT:
Home_Window
return true
result True
assert
result None
F
======================================================================
FAIL: testSi_Button_clicked (testC_Esci.tstEsci)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testC_Esci.py", line 78, in testSi_Button_clicked
    self.assertIsNotNone(result)
AssertionError: unexpectedly None
```

Comment: are you sure? Actually "result" borns in [testSi_Button_clicked] and it setted to global in [def thread]. What should I change?

Comment: I ran your example code. It also gave me None as printed result rather than 2 in your output.

Comment: awesome, I still get 2. Can some1 explain me how to do this and why?

Comment: After adding `t.join()` to the code, I was also able to get 2. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `thread`, `global result` refers to a module-level variable named `result` in the module where `testSi_Button_clicked` (or rather, the class that defines `testSi_Button_clicked`) is defined. It does not refer to the local variable of the same name that  you define in `testSi_Button_clicked`.

To fix, make `result` a mutable object (such as a `dict`), drop the `global result` statement, and let `thread` be a closure over `result`. (In Python 3, you can use the `nonlocal` keyword to avoid this kind of wrapper trickery.)

```
def testSi_Button_clicked(self):

        def thread(button=self.builder.get_object('Si_Button')):
            import time
            time.sleep(0.5)
            result['result'] = self.esci.Si_Button_clicked(button)
            print 'result ' + str(result['result'])
            #Gtk.main_quit()


        import threading

        self.current_window = 'Home_Window' #DO NOT TRY WITH 'Azioni_Window'
        result = {'result': None}
        t = threading.Thread(target=thread, args=())
        t.start()
        Gtk.main()
        print 'assert'
        print 'result ' + str(result['result'])
        self.assertIsNotNone(result['result'])
```

Comment: Ok I'll talk about the example. I've already tried that.. but cutting off _global result_ result will be None. And before this change the result was correct (2). The test after this change still doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, I confused myself while writing this. Dropping the `global` will use the correct `result`, until you try to assign to it, at which point you are assigning to a local variable. I meant to make some mention of Python 3's `nonlocal`, which I think would be correct here (if you aren't using Python 2, anyway.)

Comment: Ok so by using 2.7 there is no chance.. I can't believe

Comment: A workaround is to use something like `result_dict = {'result': None}` and pass `result_dict` as an argument to `thread`, and update the value in the dictionary.

Comment: It is very similar to something like "passing parameters by reference". So I have to use a mutable object and not changing the reference

Comment: Exactly. Although come to think of it, once `result` is a mutable object, you can go back my original answer, because you'll never be assigning to `result`, just accessing the object it references.